# Pausing a Javascript slideshow on hoverover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so Im working on this slideshow and I cant seem to get it to pause on mouseover and resume on mouse out. ["Image slideshow with navigation buttons"](http://www.siteforinfotech.com/2013/11/image-slideshow-with-navigation-buttons.html) this is the link to full code for the slideshow. Any help would be awesome the code below is what I put in to attempt to make it pause on mouse over.

```
var animate = setTimeout("swapImage()",5000);

function pause() { 
    clearTimeout(animate); 
}

function resume() { 
    setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code for handling the mouseover and mouseout events?

Comment: try <code><img ... onmouseover="pause()" onmouseout="resume()" /></code> and <code>function resume(){ animate=setTimeout("swapImage()",5000);}</code>

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get that to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First some general information about timers in JavaScript:**

Timers always generate an id. When you call upon `setTimeout` or `setInterval` these native functions return a `timer id`. In the first declaration this timer id is stored in `animate`:

```
var animate=setTimeout("swapImage()",5000);
```

However the timer stored in `animate` gets cleared when you call `clearTimeOut`. When you call `setTimeOut` again it you need to store the new id.

```
 function resume(){ animate = setTimeout(swapImage,5000);}
```

However `setTimeout` needs to be called every time you want to delay execution. `setTimeout` delays the execution of a statement with `n` where `n` is the time in milliseconds. `setInterval` repeats the statement again after `n` milliseconds.

---

Based upon the code in the link I noticed that the function `swapImage` sets `setTimeout` every time it's called.

```
function swapImage(){ 
  var el = document.getElementById("mydiv"); 
  el.innerHTML=caption[i]; 
  var img= document.getElementById("slide"); 
  img.src= image[i]; 
  if(i < k ) { i++;}  
  else  { i = 0; } 
    animate = setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
  }
```

I've added `animate` to the function. This should do the trick based upon the posted code in the link. In addition to the code below.

```
document.getElementById("slideContainer").addEventListener("mouseover", pause, false); //attach event handlers
document.getElementById("slideContainer").addEventListener("mouseout", resume, false);

function pause() { 
    clearTimeout(animate); 
}

function resume() { 
   animate = setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
}
```

This bit of code attached two event handlers (mouseover and mouseout) to your table. When somebody hovers over the table, the `mouseover` event is fired and executes the `pause` function. `mouseout` fires the `resume`. You also need to update your html. An `id` needs to be set to the table.

```html
<table id="slideContainer" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;">
```

Comment: Using setInterval won't solve the problem either. Without the OP posting their HTML, we're all kind of shooting into the dark here.

Comment: That's a good point about altering the source code for the `swapImage` function. We can't keep track of the timeout id without that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var animate=setInterval(swapImage,5000); 

 function pause(){ clearInterval(animate);} 
 function resume(){ animate=setInterval(swapImage,5000);}
```

Comment: This isn't fixing the problem. Actually the added `}` breaks this code.

Comment: Your answer does exactly the same thing as what the OP tried.

Comment: Yes sorry for that i changed it to setInterval

Answer (score 0):

The link to the slideshow library you posted suggests this HTML structure:

```
<table style="border:none;background-color:transparent;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img onclick="prev()" title="Previous" alt ="Prev" height="25" width="15"src="prev.jpg"/> 
        </td>
        <td> 
            <img name="slide" id="slide" alt ="my images" height="285" width="485" src="image-1.png"/> 
        </td> 
        <td>
            <img onclick="next()" title="Next" alt ="Next" height="25" width="15" src="next.jpg"/> 
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td></td>
        <td align="center"style="font:small-caps bold 15px georgia; color:blue;"> 
            <div id ="mydiv"></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming this HTML structure, you'll need to add event handlers to the `TABLE` tag that contains the whole slideshow (or some other tag that contains the whole slideshow):

```
<table onmouseover="pause()" onmouseout="resume()" style="...">
```

Edit: @Mouser's answer alerted me to another problem. You'll have to alter the source code for the `swapImage` function so you have access to the timeout Id:

```
function swapImage(){ 
    var el = document.getElementById("mydiv"); 
    el.innerHTML=caption[i]; 
    var img= document.getElementById("slide"); 
    img.src= image[i]; 
    if(i < k ) { i++;}  
    else  { i = 0; } 

    // Save timeout Id to implicitly declared global variable
    animate = setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
}
```